# How to display source JSON when provided programmatically to Swagger-UI?

Tags: swagger-ui

I have embedded Swagger-UI in an application.  I am providing the OpenAPI document to display programmatically by assigning the OpenApi document to the `spec` configuration property and I am not using the `url` configuration property.

```js
    this._swagger({
      domNode: this.swaggerContainer?.nativeElement,
      spec: this._options?.openApiDocument,
      deepLinking: false,
      withCredentials: false,
      tryItOutEnabled: true,
      filter: this._options?.tag?.name,
      plugins: [
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
        (_system: unknown) => {
          return {
            fn: {
              // The default filter function does a contains match on the filter expression.
              // This may be useful when filtering based on a search input but is not useful
              // when driving the filter from a tag selection in a navigation tree.  We need
              // an exact match on the tag name in this case.
              opsFilter: (
                taggedOps: TaggedOperations,
                filterExpression: string,
              ) =>
                taggedOps.filter((val, key) => {
                  return key === filterExpression;
                }),
            },
          };
        },
      ],
    });
```

No link to the OpenAPI json is displayed.

Is there a way to display the JSON that has been provided to Swagger-UI, preferably opening in a new tab?  Perhaps there is a component that will do so?